# Usefulness of blockchain technology in private sector

Tags: hash-tree

I understand that blockchain technology works for cryptocurrency.
But I don't get why it should be used in private sector.

For example, I often read that it is useful to monitor the supply chain of food.
But why is that? If a company uses blockchain technology for that, how does it work?

From my understanding, in that case it is hard to get a distributed blockchain.
But with a non-distributed blockchain, I only see disadvantages.
Why not use a good old standard database in such cases?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why is the question tagged "cryptocurrency" if it's about blockchain _not_ for cryptocurrency? And what about giving a definition of "blockchain"? The one I know is on the tune of: collection of smurfs including a signature or hash of part of itself and optionally other smurfs; but that's hardly precise enough for orderly discussion. Please also define "non-distributed".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about non-cryptographic aspects of blockchains.

Comment: wow... very helpful community here. Sorry,  for the wrong tag. I see it is not directly related to cryptocurrency, but I thought it is distantly related.
And I was not aware that this stack exchange is strictly and only used for direct cryptographic aspects. Since the blockchain is based on cryptography, I thought there are people here that might be interested in this topic. So sorry again for bothering you.

About the one question: By "non-distributed" I mean, that companies seem to use blockchain without the distributed ledger concept. So just one blockchain on their local computer.

Comment: This is a cryptography Q&A community, NOT a cryptocurrency Q&A community. We allow anything having to do with the cryptographic aspects, including questions about the cryptography of blockchains. But the currency, economic, social, etc, aspects are off-topic. Also, there's no consensus anywhere on whether Merkle trees without a distributed consensus mechanism are even blockchains. EG `git` is a blockchain to some people, and not to others. It's not a well-defined term and becomes redundant if you allow centralized consensus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why not use a good old standard database in such cases?
>
> Am I missing something?

No; you understand it perfectly well! It's nothing more than a particularly strange form of data integrity assurance (that, as you quickly realize, is trivially bypassed if not distributed across multiple nodes). If you're not using it as a resistance to adversarial peers, and you're not using it for consensus-building purposes, then there's little benefit to be wrung from prefacing each $\text{block}_n$ with $H(\text{block}_{n-1})$.

Even distributed systems such as highly-available and fault-tolerant hypervisors that have to "solve" the [Two Generals Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) accomplish their task perfectly fine with non-blockchain-based consensus algorithms.

(However, as the commenters note, this is *much* more of a systems engineering question than a cryptographic one.)

---

I will amend this answer to note that Merkle trees *per se* can be useful in situations where you require, for instance, the public to be able to easily audit or assure themselves that some log has remained append-only, such as in the [Certificate Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Transparency) security addition to HTTPS. But (again a nod to Peregrinus) **these aren't "blockchains"* since they're not being leveraged for consensus**: the scheme *itself* imposes no restrictions on [the whole thing being rewritten](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+force+push+is+evil); all the auditors can do is sound the alarm if they see a fork in the tree.

(*As evidenced by the fact that [a quick search](https://archive.is/o/www.google.com/search?q=certificate+transparency+blockchain) turns up a *whole host* of schemes proposing blockchain-based *augmentations of* CT.)

Comment: Every time I see people pushing "blockchain" as the hammer to things that aren't even nails, I'm reminded of this fictional vignette -- *Chrysus, LLC had started as joke… Our primary ambition was to persuade venture capitalists to pay for a high-rise office and a high-end coffee machine. I knew the right kind of people and I knew how to erect a Potemkin village out of the latest buzzwords. Getting money is easy, doing something useful with it is hard…*

Comment: I'd add a note that Merkle Trees are the core data structure of a "blockchain". Indeed, a blockchain is just a Merkle Tree with a "cannonical" branch to a current leaf node. With a distributed consensus algorithm, you can get a cryptocurrency. With centralized consensus, you can get something like `git`. But most of the "private blockchains" could just as well be databases, and add nothing except a way to siphon off investor's money.